# Add moving animation to divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have a problem with div transitions. I have a 2 columns of image box. When a user clicks on a box, the box description will show beside it. I want the box to animate in such a way that if the hidden description box will appear, the image it replaces will animate and move to the next row. This is what I have.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.member-image').click(function(){
    var attr = jQuery(this).attr('data-image');
    jQuery('.member-description').fadeOut();
    jQuery('div[data-description="'+ attr + '"]').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block');
  });
  
});
```

```css
.member-image,
.member-description{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.member-description{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="member-image" data-image="1">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="1">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="member-image" data-image="2">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="2">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="member-image" data-image="3">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="3">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="member-image" data-image="4">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="4">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="member-image" data-image="5">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="5">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="member-image" data-image="6">
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>

<div class="member-description" data-description="6">
  <h5>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</h5>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

This is what I want to achieve.
[Moving DIVs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAQds.gif)

Any ideas on how can I improve my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please clarify if you want the timing of show/hide to be animated or you want the tile effects seen in the animation. Please be specific, include anything you have tried. Also if this is being used on another page, a link to that page may help.

Comment: Thanks @Twisty, any timing will do.. I have included a GIF as a reference.